# Getting an “ignoring title (too short)” error when using Handbrake to convert multiple files

Tags: video-conversion, handbrake

I am trying to use Handbrake to convert multiple videos files to mp4.

I have turned on "Automatic File Naming", set the default path and changed thhe file format to `{source}`.

Adding an entire folder of 85 MP2 videos only adds 25 of them to the queue. The remaining say “ignoring title (too short).” I can convert each file individually, but this is unrealistic as I have around 500 videos to convert. What could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Handbrake options (Tools menu) under the Advanced tab there should be a "Minimum title length" option.

[image]

Set that to be shorter than your smallest clip.